# Intellij 14 suggestion text formatting messed up

Tags: intellij-idea

I was wondering if anyone has experience the InteliJ 14 suggestion text formatting bug. I can't seem to find the steps to reproduce and it does not happen all the time but a fresh restart does not seem to always fix the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution, which came from JetBrains support, was to install version 14.1 EAP with a custom JDK bundled. The download link can be found here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14.1+EAP